# SSRS Multilookup Function for Names with Comma Separation

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to put the following in a **multilookup drop-down in reporting services :**

```
"Smith, John", "Jones, Tim", "Kelly, Andy"
```

The comma separating the first and last name prevents the multilookup from working correctly. I am also unable to use ticks (' or ") in reporting service to keep the separating comma from working like a multilookup comma that separates the fields I want to select from.

Is there a way to keep the comma in the names while still allowing multilookup?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is the default multiple-valued parameter functionality not good enough? [Example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GTvFx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have the names in the `LastName, FirstName` format in a dataset:

[image: Dataset definition]

Ensure your report dataset query has the appropriate `WHERE` clause defined:

```
...
WHERE Name IN (@Name)
...
```

Modify the `@Name` parameter enabling multiple values:

[image: Multiple value parameter]

And set the `Available Values` of the parameter to the prompt dataset:

[image: Available values]

When the report is run, parameter selection will look like this:

[image: Parameter selection]

Take a look at [this set of report development tutorials](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for practice.