# SQL Server - search comma separated list against all possible values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Scenario: I have a SSRS report which has a bunch of filters. One of those filters is for "Area", I get the areas like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Area FROM tblArea ORDER BY Area
```

I have a default value of "All" for the parameter that gets its available values from that, so the output would be like:

All
Area1
Area2
China
US
etc

In the report they could select "All" which when passed to the main stored procedure the parameter would look like:

All, Area1, Area2, China, US, etc

Now here is the issue: In the table which I query the Area column might have data like:

```
Area
--------
Area2,US
```

And the query is

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE TPC IN (@Area) -- All,Area1,Area2,China,US,etc
```

And this would not find the record I am looking for.

In short, how do I compare each value in a comma separated column against a comma separated parameter?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19688758/2848551

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use the built-in multiple valued parameter functionality. Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687600/ssrs-multilookup-function-for-names-with-comma-separation/19689172#19689172).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is looking for a single value, that has a comma in it.  The `in` doesn't parse the string.

You can do what you want using `like`:

```
where @Area = 'All' or
      ','+TPC+',' like '%,'+@Area+',%';
```

The use of comma is to prevent collisions, when one area is contained in another (say, "US" and "USSR").

Comment: @Area is never set to 'ALL'. This does not help me.

Comment: That seems to contradict your original post which states "I have a default value of "All" for the parameter" - can you clarify what this means?

Comment: The default value of the SSRS parameter is All, but when that is sent to the SPROC, it is a concatenated value of all areas.

Answer (score 0):

I think below example will solve your purpose

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL
    ([Id] int, [Areas] varchar(11))
;

INSERT INTO #TBL 
    ([Id], [Areas])
VALUES
    (1, 'abc,def,ghi'),
    (2, 'abc,def'),
    (3, 'abc')
;


DECLARE @Area VARCHAR(100)  -- parameter
SET @Area = 'All,abc,def,ghi'

;with cte
as
(
    select Areaxml.s.value('.','varchar(100)') as Area
    from
    (
    select convert(xml,'<m>'+replace(@Area,',','</m><m>')+'</m>') as CArea 
    )t
    cross apply
    CArea.nodes('/m') as Areaxml(s)
)


select * FROM #TBL
where exists (select Area from cte where [Areas] LIKE '%'+ Area +'%')

DROP TABLe #TBL
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you must create a Table-valued function that will convert the comma-delimited string @Area into Table. You can then query using this table.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[List_to_tbl] (@list nvarchar(MAX))
    RETURNS @tbl TABLE (stringsTable nvarchar(10) NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @pos        int,
       @nextpos    int,
       @valuelen   int

 SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

  WHILE @nextpos > 0
       BEGIN
          SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
          SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                          THEN @nextpos
                          ELSE len(@list) + 1
                     END - @pos - 1
          INSERT @tbl (stringsTable)
              VALUES (substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen))
          SELECT @pos = @nextpos
     END
 RETURN

 END
```

Now you can call this from you Stored procedure

```
Select * from TBL where TPC in (Select stringTable from List_to_tbl(@Area))
```